# JSF can't render FacesMessage added in preRenderView

Tags: jsf, facelets, mojarra

I have a facelet page defining content of the document which looks like this:

```
<ui:composition template="template.jspx">
<ui:define name="content">
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBB.initialize}"/>
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="mainForm">
            <p:growl for="mainForm" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" escape="false" sticky="true" widgetVar="growlVar"/>
            <p:outputText value="#{myBB.value}"/>
...
```

`myBB` is a ViewScoped bean. The listener `myBB.initialize` adds FacesMessage using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(severity, title, detail)`

The problem is that the message is never shown. I've verified that the message is added to the FacesContext and that it was not cleared(I've debugged the getter `myBB.value` and the message is still in the FacesContext).

It works when I force keeping messages using `getFlash().setKeepMessages(true)`, but then I get the message multiple times. It was just a test that the growl works, not a real solution.

I've tried putting the `f:event` to different places and using `@PostContruct` method instead of `preRenderView`, but without any luck. Do I need to update the growl somehow manually after the page loads?

I use Mojarra 2.2.7

Comment: What else do you do in the prerenderevent in this case? Redirect?

Comment: I'm loading some data. But there's no redirect. I only add the message.

Comment: It started to work, when I added the FacesMessage with "mainForm" component instead of null.

Comment: Ahhhh yes, ofcourse. You had a `for` in the growl, so it does not receive global messages (the ones with id being null). Please create an answer yourself with parts of this comment and your own findig

Comment: It was a bit misleading, because I was getting the messages on subsequent reloads when using flash scope.